# Forzar dos posiciones decimales en input type="number"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

Me han pedido una cosa un poco rara, que los campos `input` numéricos de una pagina JSP tengan 2 decimales por defecto.

Hasta aquí todo normal:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
```

Ahora bien, el cliente quiere que las cantidades SIEMPRE tengan 2 posiciones decimales, incluso para 0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debería ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O sea, mientras usas las flechas para aumentar la cantidad o cargas desde la base de datos un valor con ceros en las posiciones decimales que este valor no se recorte (o sea, sobreescribir el comportamiento por defecto que ignora los ceros a la derecha)

## MVCE

https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/ezog2m13/5/

Lo he intendado con `pattern="regex"`:

```
^\d+\.\d{2}$
\d.{2}$
```

pero no parece funcionar.

---

**AÑADIDOS**

- Tal y como ha apuntado [rnd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/25/rnd): http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003896
- He intentado solución via `html` pero si a alguien se le ocurre algo en `javascript` / `jquery` que lo solucione, también me vale :).

Comment: Dato: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003896

Comment: espero interesado una respuesta sobre esto, es una buena pregunta.

Comment: @rnd algun tag mas que se te ocurra para darle mas visibilidad a la pregunta? no he encontrado más... :S

Comment: el problema parece ser que las reglas que se aplican para representar el numero son las mismas reglas que se usan en `toString` para numero de coma flotante en javascript ([fuente](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#best-representation-of-the-number-as-a-floating-point-number)). .. habria que ver que pasa si se sobre escribe ese metodo.. pero aunque funcione no es una buena practica, en terminos generales. si aceptas una solucion con javascript, yo agregaria ese tag. que es ademas es el mas popular de todos.

Answer (score 3):

No puedes utilizar el atributo `pattern` con `type="number"`, como se explica en [MDN (propiedad pattern)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties)

> Este atributo se aplica cuando el valor de type es text, search, tel, url o email; de otro modo, sera ignorado.

Este enfoque en JavaScript es muy simple y funciona. <strike>Pero no es la solución mas óptima/deseable, pues durante una fracción de segundo muestra el valor `1.1` antes de actualizarse a `1.10`, sin embargo puede sacarte del bloqueo.</strike> .

Gracias @AlvaroMontoro! que ha comentado que utilizando `input` en lugar de `change` el efecto de latencia desaparece.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("in")

// te aseguras que el valor inicial tiene el formato correcto
el.value = el.valueAsNumber.toFixed(2)

// manejador que asegura que el valor tiene el formato correcto cuando 
// se modifica el valor, ya sea manual o con los botones inc/dec
el.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  event.target.value = event.target.valueAsNumber.toFixed(2)
});
```

```html
<input id="in" value="1" type="number" step="0.01">
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Si usas el evento `input` en lugar de `change` no se ve el formato incorrecto durante una décima de segundo

Comment: el problema ahora es el valor inicial, no se formatea hasta haber cambiado: https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/ezog2m13/5/

Comment: @JordiCastilla eso es facil de arreglar, fijate mi edicion, igual tiene el problema de no permitir ingresar datos manualmente, es por eso que puse change en primer lugar, pero bueno no parece que halla una solución optima.

Answer (score -1):

Aconsejaria uses un plugin de jquery para aplicar una mascara sobre el textbox

[Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

[Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

La idea es que la mascara limite el input del usuario en el control.

```js
$(function(){
  
    $("#textbox1").mask("9999.99");

  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="textbox1">
```

Por supuesto esto es solo un ejemplo, habria que analizar si se puede definir una mascara que se adapte a lo que buscas. La idea es no validar sino que la mascara limite lo que el usuario ingresa

Comment: Hola Leandro, lo he probado y no funciona. Prueba cambiando a type= number y step=0.01 y cuando utilizas los botones up y down vuelve a 1.1 sin el cero. Saludos

Comment: @rnd pero es una mascara que aplica al textbox, no afecta el type que se aplique, ademas a que botones up o down te refieres ?

Comment: El problema es que trabaja con tipo del elemento type="text" y el OP quiere usar number, por los botones de incrementar y decrementar basados en el atributo step. https://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/cmaxyyrj/ produce este error `The input element's type ('number') does not support selection.`